# How to determine amount of data prefetched from file system when a C program performs sequential reads()?

Tags: c, operating-system, filesystems

I am preparing for my exams by doing some textbook practice questions. I am stuck at one of the questions which asks us to find how much data is prefetched by the file system during a sequential read of a large file?(C program performs multiple `reads()` in a loop) It says we should plot the data and observe the graph to determine that amount of data that gets prefetched.

The textbook gives us this hint:

Hint: time each read and plot the time per read.

I am confused about the following:

1) Does sequential read mean that I have to read the same size over and over again till the end of the file? (Eg: 10 bytes per read)

2) I dont really get how would graphing the results help determine the amount of data is prefetched? Is there anything particular that would stand out to indicate the amount of data that is prefetched?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The general idea is that `read()` will return very quickly if the data was already buffered because of prefetching, while it will take longer if it has to go to disk. So read 1 byte at a time, and see how often it slows down.

Comment: @Barmar After doing some experimenting, I see a pattern in blocks of MB'S? Is it typical for prefetched data to be in the size of MB's and not KB's?

Comment: That's certainly possible. See the section on Disk Readahead in http://www.overclock.net/t/388475/linux-performance-tuning, it shows the command to see the readahead setting.